# flutter dart: how to encode a map / dictionary to JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, encoding

I managed to decode a JSON dictionary but how can I do the opposite - encoding?

```dart
class Achievements {
  Achievements({this.skills});
  var skills = Map<String, SkillHist>();
// ==================================================ENCODING DICTIONARY
  factory Achievements.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var innerMap = json['skills'];
    var skillMap = Map<String, SkillHist>();
    innerMap.forEach((key, value) {
      skillMap.addAll({key: SkillHist.fromJson(value)});
    });
    return Achievements(
      skills: skillMap,
    );
  }
// ==================================================DECODING DICTIONARY
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "skills": skills == null ? null : Map // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  };
}

class SkillHist {
  SkillHist({this.currentSkill, this.skillLevel, this.skillEarnedDate});
  final int currentSkill;
  final List<int> skillLevel;
  final List<DateTime> skillEarnedDate;

  factory SkillHist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SkillHist(
    currentSkill: json["currentSkill"] == null ? null : json['currentSkill'],
    skillLevel: json["skillLevel"] == null ? null : List<int>.from(json["skillLevel"].map((x) => x)),
    skillEarnedDate: json["skillEarnedDate"] == null ? null : List<DateTime>.from(json["skillEarnedDate"].map((x) => x)),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "currentSkill": currentSkill == null ? null : currentSkill,
    "skillLevel": skillLevel == null ? null : List<int>.from(skillLevel.map((x) => x)),
    "skillEarnedDate": skillEarnedDate == null ? null : List<DateTime>.from(skillEarnedDate.map((x) => x)),
  };
}
```

With this issue in mind, I also started wondering how I implemented the decoding of a List, which I copied from some snippet, months ago.
Why am I using

```
"skillEarnedDate": List<DateTime>.from(skillEarnedDate.map((x) => x)),
```

and not simply

```
"skillEarnedDate": skillEarnedDate,
```

`skillEarnedDate` is a List already, so why do I have initiate a new one?